# What is Likely the Zenith of the Curve Representing Access to Destructive Power?

Tags: science-based, society, technology

**Premise**

In the distant past, with only rocks and clubs, a **single** person's lethality on society most likely did not reach a genocidal scale. In the near/medium-distant future, with the advent of rapidly advancing technology, the destructive power available to a single person will reach unprecedented levels (at least in my fictional world). Of course, armed with the proper intel, the aforementioned rogue caveman could still cause serious damage to his sleeping tribesmen. I am the first to admit there are other factors, but I simply wish to make a clear case that, ceteris paribus, technology is a major factor governing the maximum amount of damage able to be caused to society by said rogue individual.

While there may be little to suggest that technology itself will ever reach a zenith, but there may be a self-imposed limit/zenith, inasmuch that given the law of large numbers, any freak accident/rogue attack that could happen will eventually happen. After such a calamity, the world may have been reduced to a simpler technological ecosystem if it did not exterminate itself altogether.

**Question**

If we analyze this relationship (mathematically, philosophically, or otherwise) what is the logical zenith? Of course, this is all essentially a stochastic outcome. If we could sit back and watch this world play itself out over 10,000 (or more) simulations, the zenith of destructive power available to an individual could be different each time. So to simplify things, let us evaluate this chaotic process at its mean. When you give your answer, think about the overall tendency. That is to say, think about what would happen most of the time in the simulations.

**Further Clarification**
You may stipulate societal and technology assumptions as needed. For example,

- A benevolent society would could have omnipotent technology
- A hostility-prone society would have sub-omnipotent techology
- For extrapolating purposes, assume present day
- Answer may include some social engineering solutions, but I wish to
  avoid dehumanizing solutions (lobotomizing, genetic engineering, ect)
- Zentith can assume a pre-existing technology (nukes) or frontier
  techonology (nano-bots, grey ooze)
- Explain major driving factors of why your theoretical zenith would be
  the most logical outcome

Comment: Somebody already played with a nuclear reactor in the basketball field of a university and polluted it to a great deal. And was lucky enough to not blow Chicago out. What other zenith are you looking for?

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking, there are many questions all mixed together here, and a lot of countering qualifiers. Can you clarify a specific question. Are you asking what the most destructive technology available today is?

Comment: Arash, this gwine be a difficult one to answer.  Even before that, please allow me to question a few premises.  First, we are talking about **individuals** and their choices, so it wouldn't be "safe" for even a benevolent society to have omnipotent technology ... all it takes is one bad apple.  Second, please specify whether your planet has just one society or not ... if many societies, this complicates the calculation immensely.

Comment: Third, are you asking for an indefinite zenith?  If any one person has access to calamity-making technology, you might be able to calculate mean-time-before-disaster...

Comment: You may want to roll this one around the sandbox for a while.

Comment: @John that is a really good idea!  There is the kernel of a fantastic SE question here, but I do fear that the scope will need narrowing before it is safe from "too-broad"-closure.  Arash, please do not get discouraged if question is held.  You've got a great idea here, it just needs some nip & tuck work...

Comment: hi I'm the "energy" person if you followed most of my recent comments, so it's depend on the energy consumption and efficiency of the tech of that particular period. Now we discovered that fusing quarks produce eight times more energy than with hydrogen atom, so that's that. ;D

Comment: I think this depends not on the technology but how large percentage of a population could be potentially exterminated by one strike, right? So if your population spans hundreds of galaxies then even technology which can destroy ten or more galaxies at the same time might not make a dent.